# Tornado version conflict between Jupyter Server and Anaconda?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, tornado

I was attempting Git integration of nbdime when I ran into an apparent conflict between the Tornado version requirements between the Jupyter Server and Anaconda.

Jupyter server error :

```
nbdime config-git --enable --global
......
ImportError: The Jupyter Server requires tornado >=6.1.0
```

Anaconda error:

```
conda update tornado
......
Updating tornado is constricted by
anaconda -> requires tornado==6.0.4=py38he774522_1
```

Anyone else run into this issue?